# Mouse hover functionality using selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mousehover

I want to mousehover over image icon, then dropdown list is displayed later want to click on first option from drop-down list.

I tried with all these options but non of them work for me. Please suggest

```
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement iconhover =driver.findElement(By.className("insertItems"));
    act.moveToElement(iconhover).click().build().perform();
    WebElement ModulesAndTopics = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Topics']"));
    ModulesAndTopics.click();
```

Another try

```
driver.switchTo().window(subwindow);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("insertItems"));
Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) element;
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
```

Comment: i have posted my answer, does it help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hover over the dropdown list and perform a click.

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
WebElement iconhover =driver.findElement(By.className("insertItems"));
act.moveToElement(iconhover).click().build().perform();
WebElement ModulesAndTopics = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Topics']"));
act.moveToElement(ModulesAndTopics).click().build().perform();   //hover and click
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, if not solved your problem then please provide me your HTML, So I can check:

```
new Actions(driver).
    moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.className("insertItems")))
      .build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    //If //*[@title='Topics'] is xpath of your dropdown select tag
    Select sel=new Select(wd.findElement(By.xpath("By.xpath("//*[@title='Topics']")")));
    sel.selectByIndex(Index_OF_Option);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are dealing with a menu item. I am assuming className = "insertItems" is unique.

```
//Locate the image icon
WebElement iconhover = driver.findElement(By.className("insertItems"));

//Hover mouse above the image icon - **DONT click**
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(iconhover).build().perform();

//Locating the first menu item - *plz use tagname instead of * in xpath* as its preferable
WebElement modulesAndTopics = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Topics']"));
modulesAndTopics.click();
```

Please note that sometimes the drop down list takes some time to open so its advisable to use Explicit Wait while locating the menu item - "modulesAndTopics", like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
WebElement modulesAndTopics = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@title='Topics']")));
modulesAndTopics.click();
```

Comment: yes, className = "insertItems" is unique. Now so far got a success on hover dropdown list is displayed. But still not able to click on  first option. tried with   WebElement modulesAndTopics = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Topics']"));
modulesAndTopics.click();    throws an error javascript(0)

Comment: Here is Div code                                                                     <li class="insertItems" tabindex="1">
<a title="Insert" href="#">
<ul>
<li class="standardContent">
<a id="id548" title="Modules & Topics from a Library" href="#"> Modules & Topics from a Library </a>
</li>
<li class="customModule">

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code, it seems you have not used Select class:

```
WebElement iconhover = driver.findElement(By.className("insertItems"));       
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);    
builder.moveToElement(iconhover).build().perform();    
WebElement abc=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Topics']");    
Select drop= new Select(abc);    
drop.selectByVisibleText("xyz");
```